# Why doesn't android:text display latest LiveData value?

Tags: android, android-livedata

The following code is based the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-databinding).

I modified a few code.

The `android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"` displays the `LiveData` value of the `name`.

The `fun onLike()` will change `LiveData` value of the `name`.

I think `android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"` will display latest value "My new" after I click the button (`android:id="@+id/like_button"`).

But in fact, `android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"` keep to display "Ada", why?

**SimpleViewModelSolution.kt**

```
class SimpleViewModelSolution : ViewModel() {
    private var _name = MutableLiveData("Ada")     // I modified from private val _name = MutableLiveData("Ada")
   
    val name: LiveData<String> = _name
  
     ...

    fun onLike() {
        _likes.value = (_likes.value ?: 0) + 1
        _name = MutableLiveData("My new")  // I added
    }
}
```

**solution.xml**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.android.databinding.basicsample.data.SimpleViewModelSolution"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"
           ..."/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/like_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.onLike()}"
            android:text="@string/like"
           .../>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onLike()` to this:

```
fun onLike() {
    _likes.value = (_likes.value ?: 0) + 1
    _name.value = "My new"
}
```

Also, you can declare `_name` as `val` instead of `var`

Comment: Thanks! your code works well, why don't my code  work?

Comment: You were creating a new instance of `_name` instead of just changing its value.

Comment: On a side note, don't use a `var` declaration for `_name`, use `val` instead. LiveData references are better kept immutable.